# How to show a specific array value first in UICollectionView when scrolling horizontally in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am getting Array from JSON to show data on collectionview

JSON data structure is like this:

```
            {
                id = 9;
                image = "1685696735-5869.jpg";
                "user_id" = 13;
            },
            {
                id = 17;
                image = "1685709043-8696.jpg";
                "user_id" = 13;
            },.... so on
```

i am getting **selectedID and selectedImage** value now i need to show that selectedID array value first in the collectionview

for eg selectedImage = 1685709043-8696.jpg then i need to show `image = "1685709043-8696.jpg"` first in collectionview first cell how to do that

**code:** here if `getImagesData?.result?.userToGallery` or `selectedDataArray` contains **`selectedImage`** then that cell should show first in imagecollectionView and remaining should scroll horizontally

```swift
class AllGalleryImgViewController: UIViewController {
    
   private var getImagesData = GetGalleryImageModel(dictionary: NSDictionary()){
        didSet{
            
            self.selectedDataArray = getImagesData?.result?.userToGallery ?? []
            imagecollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
    public var selectedDataArray = [UserToGallery]()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var imagecollectionView: UICollectionView!
    var selectedImage: String!
    var selectedID: Int!
    var imagesArray = [String]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getImagesServiceCall()
    }
    func getImagesServiceCall() {
        
        APIReqeustManager.sharedInstance.serviceCall(param: nil, method: .get, url: CommonUrl.my_gallery_image){ [weak self] (resp) in
            
            self?.getImagesData = GetGalleryImageModel(dictionary: resp.dict as NSDictionary? ?? NSDictionary())
        }
    }
    }
    extension AllGalleryImgViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return getImagesData?.result?.userToGallery?.count ?? 0 //10
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "AllBigGalleryCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! AllBigGalleryCollectionCell
        
        cell.galleryImageView.getImage(withImagePath: getImagesData?.result?.userToGallery?[indexPath.item].image ?? "")
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

How to filer array and show that value in collectionview first cell

i need to show filtered image first in `cell.galleryImageView.getImage(withImagePath: getImagesData?.result?.userToGallery?[indexPath.item].image ?? "")` and remaining should show next when scrolling horizontally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the selected image first in the collection view ,

Modify your `selectedDataArray` property to hold the filtered array with the selected image at the beginning,

```
var selectedDataArray = [UserToGallery]() {
    didSet {
        if let selectedImage = selectedImage {
            let filteredArray = selectedDataArray.filter { $0.image == selectedImage }
            let remainingArray = selectedDataArray.filter { $0.image != selectedImage }
            self.selectedDataArray = filteredArray + remainingArray
        }
    }
}
```

In the `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` method, access the image from the filtered array using `indexPath.item`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "AllBigGalleryCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! AllBigGalleryCollectionCell
    
    cell.galleryImageView.getImage(withImagePath: selectedDataArray[indexPath.item].image)
    
    return cell
}
```

Update the `collectionView(_:numberOfItemsInSection:)` method to return the count of the filtered array,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return selectedDataArray.count
}
```